# Time difference calculation based on timezone and offset

Tags: sql-server, datediff, datetimeoffset

We transfer data from Oracle SQL to SQL Server in the near real-time data warehouse. (Oracle is a transactional database) The time changes twice a year for the data we use. We have been having issues when calculating DateTime differences and I have to work on a short-term and long-term solutions where I need advice.

1. New data coming in :
   I can create tables from scratch and use datetimeoffset data field for all the time variables. Would this
   display dates in SQL Server queries in the local time zone and save them in their actual UTC time? And when I
   calculate the differences, would it give the correct difference?
2. Existing data without offset information:
   I already have data converted into the current timezone. We have 2 timezones AEST and AEDT.
   When we calculate time differences for KPIs it gives incorrect times. Any ideas on how it can be resolved?
   Can creating a function that converts the dates and times into UTC and subtracts the difference and returns the value would work?

An example below :

```
DECLARE @startdate DateTime = '2022-10-01 23:13:00.000'; --UTC 2022-10-01 13:13:00.00
DECLARE @enddate DateTime = '2022-10-02 12:08:00.000' --UTC 2022-10-02 01:08:00.00
select CAST((@enddate - @startdate) as time(0)) 'Difference'

Time difference: 12:55:00

Actual Time Difference: 11:55:00
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, if you include the time zone info with the data, the date calculations work out

```sql
DECLARE @startdate datetimeoffset(0) = '2022-10-01 23:13:00 +10:00'; --UTC 2022-10-01 13:13:00.00
DECLARE @enddate datetimeoffset(0) = '2022-10-02 12:08:00 +11:00' --UTC 2022-10-02 01:08:00.00

declare @minutes int =  datediff(minute, @startdate, @enddate);

select @startdate at time zone 'utc', 
   @enddate at time zone 'utc';

select [hours] = @minutes / 60,
    [minutes] = @minutes - 60 * (@minutes / 60)
```

To address the existing data, you can do a one-time conversion to `datetimeoffset` by running it through `at time zone` with the appropriate time zone name. In my example above, I used UTC but you can find all of the supported time zones in `sys.time_zone_info`.

As to your first question about the internal storage format and display, I'm not sure if it uses UTC internally or not. As to display, it will, by default, output them with the time zone that you stored them with. That is, if you stored a given value with +10:00 as the offset, that's how it will display. You can convert via methods already described above or with `switchoffset()`. Lastly, if it matters, you can get just the offset with `datepart` noting that it returns the offset in number of minutes (to conform with datepart needing to return an int).